How to add a project property sheet (Visual Studio) for each configuration (Debug and Release) in CMake?
I have 2 .props files, one is for Debug, and the other one is for Release. I've tried 2 ways below using generator expressions, but none of them works, no file is added/shown in the Property Manager window in Visual Studio:
set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Include/prop_sheet_Debug.props>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Include/prop_sheet_Release.props>
)

set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Include/prop_sheet_$<CONFIG>.props")

This works, but it'll add the prop_sheet_Debug.props file to both Debug and Release configurations of the target (shown in the Property Manager window), which is undesirable:
set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Include/prop_sheet_Debug.props")

Is it possible at all to add prop_sheet_Debug.props for the Debug config and prop_sheet_Release.props for the Release config using CMake?

Documentation for property VS_USER_PROPS doesn't note that the property may contain generator expression. Usually (in CMake documentation) this means, that generator expressions are not supported for a specific property.

Bummer... Thanks for pointing it out! I guess one workaround is to pass in a value for CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and check its value in the CMake file, although it'll probably still add the same .props file to both Debug and Release.
